# Solving limit problems which include "e"

Tags: limits

Can anyone give me some hints on starting to prove the following

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x-\sin x}{x-\sin x}=1$$

Comment: The right limit is $+ \infty$ and the left limit is $- \infty$. It does not approach to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{\pm}} x-\sin x = [0^{\pm}]=0\,$, so
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{\pm}} \frac{ e^x - \sin x}{x-\sin x} =\left[\frac{1}{0^{\pm}}\right] = \pm \infty $$

Comment: So the question is incorrect right?

Comment: You asked if anyone can give you hints on starting to prove your equation... So there is a hint - don't start :)